# make Xcode build fail or at least warning if I use methods from "future" SDK version, relative to Target SDK version

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

The problem is my app target is iOS 7.0
I'm using SDK 8.1 to build app with Xcode. And getting no warnings, no errors on methods available in SDK 8.+ only.

this compiles easy:

```
if ([test containsString:@"CRASH"]) {
    test = @"this code will never run on iOS 7";
}
```

Is there a way to crash a build If Im building an app for iOS 7.0 and using any methods available only since SDK 8? Ideally, If I'm using anything from "future" SDK versions?

Comment: Why do you want the build to fail? The code is fine on iOS 8 devices. You need to app proper runtime checks.

Comment: @maddy because I can easily "autocomplete" with method, which will crash an app in iOS 7. The point is to make strict check of API use.